# Error $.fn.DataTable.TableTools is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabletools

I have the following function in a template I bought online. I downloaded and referenced the TableTools library, but the call `$.fn.DataTable.TableTools()` is always `undefined` for TableTools.

How do I initialize the TableTools in this function `initDataTableHelper()`?

```
function initDataTableHelper () {
        if ($.fn.dataTable) {
            $('[data-provide="datatable"]').each (function () { 
                $(this).addClass ('dataTable-helper');      
                var defaultOptions = {
                        paginate: false,
                        search: false,
                        info: false,
                        lengthChange: false,
                        displayRows: 10,
                        sRowSelect: "single"
                    },
                    dataOptions = $(this).data (),
                    helperOptions = $.extend (defaultOptions, dataOptions),
                    $thisTable,
                    tableConfig = {};

                tableConfig.iDisplayLength = helperOptions.displayRows;
                tableConfig.bFilter = true;
                tableConfig.bSort = true;
                tableConfig.bPaginate = false;
                tableConfig.bLengthChange = false;  
                tableConfig.bInfo = false;

                if (helperOptions.paginate) { tableConfig.bPaginate = true; }
                if (helperOptions.lengthChange) { tableConfig.bLengthChange = true; }
                if (helperOptions.info) { tableConfig.bInfo = true; }       
                if (helperOptions.search) { $(this).parent ().removeClass ('datatable-hidesearch'); }               

                tableConfig.aaSorting = [];
                tableConfig.aoColumns = [];

                $(this).find ('thead tr th').each (function (index, value) {
                    var sortable = ($(this).data ('sortable') === true) ? true : false;
                    tableConfig.aoColumns.push ({ 'bSortable': sortable });

                    if ($(this).data ('direction')) {
                        tableConfig.aaSorting.push ([index, $(this).data ('direction')]);
                    }
                });     

                // Create the datatable
                $thisTable = $(this).dataTable (tableConfig);

                if (!helperOptions.search) {
                    $thisTable.parent ().find ('.dataTables_filter').remove ();
                }

                var filterableCols = $thisTable.find ('thead th').filter ('[data-filterable="true"]');

                if (filterableCols.length > 0) {
                    var columns = $thisTable.fnSettings().aoColumns,
                        $row, th, $col, showFilter;

                    $row = $('<tr>', { cls: 'dataTable-filter-row' }).appendTo ($thisTable.find ('thead'));

                    for (var i=0; i<columns.length; i++) {
                        $col = $(columns[i].nTh.outerHTML);
                        showFilter = ($col.data ('filterable') === true) ? 'show' : 'hide';

                        th = '<th class="' + $col.prop ('class') + '">';
                        th += '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm ' + showFilter + '" placeholder="' + $col.text () + '">';
                        th += '</th>';
                        $row.append (th);
                    }

                    $row.find ('th').removeClass ('sorting sorting_disabled sorting_asc sorting_desc sorting_asc_disabled sorting_desc_disabled');

                    $thisTable.find ('thead input').keyup( function () {
                        $thisTable.fnFilter( this.value, $thisTable.oApi._fnVisibleToColumnIndex( 
                            $thisTable.fnSettings(), $thisTable.find ('thead input[type=text]').index(this) ) );
                    });

                    $thisTable.addClass ('datatable-columnfilter');
                }
            });

            $('.dataTables_filter input').prop ('placeholder', 'Search...');
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no reference to `$.fn.DataTable.TableTools` in the code.

Comment: Add `dom: 'T<"clear">t'` option to `var defaultOptions = {\* ... *\, dom: 'T<"clear">t' },` to initialize TableTools as shown [here](https://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/simple.html). Otherwise if you're loading JS/CSS/SWF in the correct order, you should be able to do [direct initialization](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/initialisation#Direct-initialisation) as well after the call to `$(this).dataTable (tableConfig)`.

Comment: Both ways did not work. Its still undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please show how do you load your DataTables/TableTools JS files? Also what is the exact message in the console if you add this `var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( $thisTable, {});` after `$thisTable = $(this).dataTable (tableConfig);`?

Comment: edited code is above. var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools($thisTable, {}); - The TableTools is still undefined.

Comment: `dataTables.tableTools.min.js` should be loaded AFTER `jquery.dataTables.min.js`, can you please confirm that it is so.

Comment: bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/CustomContent/js").Include(
                                    "~/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
                                  "~/js/plugins/datatables/extras/TableTools-2.0.0/media/js/TableTools.min.js"
                        ));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82541/discussion-between-gyrocode-com-and-james-makinde).

Answer (score 2):

You're using DataTables 1.9.4 and TableTools 2.0.0. This version of TableTools didn't have `$.fn.DataTable.TableTools()` function then.

Instead it could be initialized by adding `sDom: 'T<"clear">t'` as follows:

```
                tableConfig = {
                   "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                   "oTableTools": {
                      "sRowSelect": "single"
                  }
                };
```

However I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of DataTables (1.10.7) and TableTools (2.2.4). Not only `$.fn.DataTable.TableTools()` will become available, but you will benefit from all the updates. DataTables 1.10.x branch is backward compatible with 1.9.x branch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Using npm I installed the following versions which fixed it for me

```
"datatables": "1.10.7",
"datatable-tabletools":"2.2.20"
```

Making sure all files and jquery are in scope could also help potential issues.